# last record of subreport is repeating on next page of report

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I created Report which is embedded with one subreport, when i Run the report then In some cases the last record of subreport is repeated on next page. I tried putting a float line just after the detail band of subreport but its not reflecting any changes. has someone also faces this earlier, please share how to tackle this

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question is hard to answer since it is very short, unspecific and without images of the current and wanted behaviour or source code. Please extend your question and give a little more context (see also [How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)).

Comment: You need to create a [mcve] (some jrxml, example of datasource ecc) otherwise we can not help you and question will be probably be closed.